# Compare days in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, linq

There is a set of records with a created date field in a table. How do I select all the records that were created on a given day of the week. e.g. all records that were created on a Monday, it could be this Monday, last Monday or the Monday before.

This is what I have written so far:

```
from ob in obList
where SqlFunctions.DateDiff("days", today, ob.StartDate) % 7 == 0
select ob.CustomerOnboardingId
```

But I get an error on this:

> {"This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities."}

Update 1:

obList is a collection in memory.
And today is variable that holds DateTime.Today;

Comment: What is `obList`?

Comment: obList is a collection in memory. I have updated the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error specifies you are trying to execute a method of Linq to Entities in-memory which can't be done. When a linq query, in the context of a linq2Sql or EF is executed it is translated into an sql and that is when functions such as the one you used get their meaning - They implement how to do it in sql. In the in-memory collections they have no meaning.

*(It is just like you will try to execute a method defined in your code on a linq-to-entities query and will get that it is not supported by linq-to-entities)*

Instead of calculating `(day1 - day2) % 7` you can use the `DayOfWeek` property of `DateTime`:

```
DateTime day = new DateTime(2016, 1, 15); // Friday

List<dynamic> collection = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { CustomerOnboardingId = "Item1", StartDate = new DateTime(2016,1,1) }, // Friday
    new { CustomerOnboardingId = "Item2", StartDate = new DateTime(2016,1,2) },
    new { CustomerOnboardingId = "Item3", StartDate = new DateTime(2016,1,8) }, // Friday
};

var result = (from item in collection
              where item.StartDate.DayOfWeek == day.DayOfWeek
              select item.CustomerOnboardingId).ToList();

// result = Item1, Item3
```

Comment: @Libin Joseph - Glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call that function to get the difference of days, which, as the exception said, it can be only used in Linq to Entities. In Linq to Objects you can do the following:

```
from ob in obList
where (today - ob.StartDate).TotalDays  % 7 == 0
select ob.CustomerOnboardingId
```

Comment: Depends what `obList` is. Feels like an in-memory variable based on the name but the OP says it represents a table. You could use AsEnumerable() to force evaluation in C# rather than the DB but that comes with a large performance penalty if it is a large database table.

Comment: Agreed @EricJ, I'm assuming `obList` is a collection that is in memory.

Comment: `in a table` would seem to invalidate that assumption but hopefully the OP will clear it up.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. ob is a collection in memory

Comment: But to be honest, i thought it would not matter, because I thought Linq works with almost same with all set of data